# Where does Synaptic (Debian) stores the installed packages list?

Tags: debian, apt, synaptic

I have to reinstall my system (Debian Linux), and need to install the same packages I previously installed with Synaptic.

Synaptic has menu options to save and reload a file which contains a list of the installed packages.

Since I cannot use the GUI (I am dealing with a broken system), how can I perform these operations from the command line?

I did not save such a list in the past, so I would need to do it now. Is it possible to do it with Synaptic from the command line? Can I use `apt`? Is there a file with the list of installed packages, even if I did not ask to create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg --get-selections > list.txt
```

then:

```
dpkg --set-selections < list.txt
apt-get -f install
```

But if you want to end up with the same working system like you have now, it's easier (and faster) to fix the errors than reinstalling everything from zero.

Comment: Yes, I will keep trying to fix it for a while. However I also needed this trick to clone my system on different machines, with different architectures.